# Is scrollView.setOnTouchListener necessary?

Tags: android, scrollview, ontouchlistener

I am fairly new to Android and I am looking at a project that has a scroll view in it with the following listener attached to it.

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

To my understanding, the project has this so that the scroll view..well.. scrolls (or hides the keyboard).  However, when I comment out this code and rerun the project, the scroll view still scrolls (and hides the keyboard) just fine.  **So, is there any purpose for this code?**

Comment: If you look at the code inside the listener it has nothing to do with scrolling. Meaning the ScrollView will scroll the same with or without it. **The code makes sure software keyboard hides when you attempt to scroll the ScrollView.**

Comment: @EugenPechanec I checked that as well but the keyboard does hide even without this code

Comment: Hmm... Did you verify it behaves the same across many versions of Android (2.3, 4.0, 4.1, 4.4, 5.1, 6.0...)? I'm assuming the author had a device where the keyboard didn't hide automatically. Otherwise the code seems useless, right?

Comment: @EugenPechanec Interesting thought. I haven't tried it on many versions of Android.  I suppose that it possible that the default functionality to hide the keyboard when a ScrollView scrolls could have been added in more recent versions?